# Migrate Custom Links to Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning, custom-link

In classic left navigation bar, I have Custom Links on home tab under Useful Links section. These link connect to external application (something like http://Test.domain.com/createUserForm). 
In Lightning experience, when I navigate to same Useful Links section, I do not see these custom links under Useful Links section. I think, may be because these links are not supposed to be available in Ligntning, as per my knowledge. Please correct me if I am wrong.
Now the question is, how do I convert these links so that they are available in both classic and lightning? Any links to blogs or examples appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sidebar will not be available as Lightning Experience is based on mobile first design approach.

Possible solution is :

**For Lightning Experience:**

1. Put your custom links in one custom object
2. Create one lightning component and add this to all app pages/record pages/home pages.

**For Classic:**

1. Put your custom links in custom object
2. Create one home page component and add this to sidebar.

Comment: Thank you Himanshu for quick response. For classic I already have home page component with the links. As per your suggestion in #1, I will use that approach, just looking for some example as I have never worked with lightning components. Also one follow up question,  if the application is not using lightning components, will I be able to use the lightning component?

Answer (score 0):

Seconding Himanshu's answer. Idea for the idea exchange for that is here: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dz41AAC

Comment: I agree with Himanshu's answer. However my ink is merely opening a jsp form in a new window. So instead of creating a lightning component for this purpose I added a Rich text area to Lightning experience home page and added my links in there. It's working as expected. If there are any red flags you experts see in this approach please let me know.